# Is it possible to decode an encoded PEM SSL certificate without OpenSSL in CLI?

Tags: tls, pem

It is said that PEM certificates are encoded with ASCII (Base64), excluding labels.
Let's take this certificate as an example.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEMjCCAxqgAwIBAgIBATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADB7MQswCQYDVQQGEwJHQjEb
MBkGA1UECAwSR3JlYXRlciBNYW5jaGVzdGVyMRAwDgYDVQQHDAdTYWxmb3JkMRow
GAYDVQQKDBFDb21vZG8gQ0EgTGltaXRlZDEhMB8GA1UEAwwYQUFBIENlcnRpZmlj
YXRlIFNlcnZpY2VzMB4XDTA0MDEwMTAwMDAwMFoXDTI4MTIzMTIzNTk1OVowezEL
MAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgMEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4GA1UE
BwwHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgGA1UECgwRQ29tb2RvIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxITAfBgNVBAMM
GEFBQSBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZSBTZXJ2aWNlczCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEP
ADCCAQoCggEBAL5AnfRu4ep2hxxNRUSOvkbIgwadwSr+GB+O5AL686tdUIoWMQua
BtDFcCLNSS1UY8y2bmhGC1Pqy0wkwLxyTurxFa70VJoSCsN6sjNg4tqJVfMiWPPe
3M/vg4aijJRPn2jymJBGhCfHdr/jzDUsi14HZGWCwEiwqJH5YZ92IFCokcdmtet4
YgNW8IoaE+oxox6gmf049vYnMlhvB/VruPsUK6+3qszWY19zjNoFmag4qMsXeDZR
rOme9Hg6jc8P2ULimAyrL58OAd7vn5lJ8S3frHRNG5i1R8XlKdH5kBjHYpy+g8cm
ez6KJcfA3Z3mNWgQIJ2P2N7Sw4ScDV7oL8kCAwEAAaOBwDCBvTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU
oBEKIz6W8Qfs4q8p74Klf9AwpLQwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQF
MAMBAf8wewYDVR0fBHQwcjA4oDagNIYyaHR0cDovL2NybC5jb21vZG9jYS5jb20v
QUFBQ2VydGlmaWNhdGVTZXJ2aWNlcy5jcmwwNqA0oDKGMGh0dHA6Ly9jcmwuY29t
b2RvLm5ldC9BQUFDZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZVNlcnZpY2VzLmNybDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUF
AAOCAQEACFb8AvCb6P+k+tZ7xkSAzk/ExfYAWMymtrwUSWgEdujm7l3sAg9g1o1Q
GE8mTgHj5rCl7r+8dFRBv/38ErjHT1r0iWAFf2C3BUrz9vHCv8S5dIa2LX1rzNLz
Rt0vxuBqw8M0Ayx9lt1awg6nCpnBBYurDC/zXDrPbDdVCYfeU0BsWO/8tqtlbgT2
G9w84FoVxp7Z8VlIMCFlA2zs6SFz7JsDoeA3raAVGI/6ugLOpyypEBMs1OUIJqsi
l2D4kF501KKaU73yqWjgom7C12yxow+ev+to51byrvLjKzg6CYG1a4XXvi3tPxq3
smPi9WIsgtRqAEFQ8TmDn5XpNpaYbg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I tried to decode this data with ASCII (Base64) decoders but to no avail:

```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```

How can I decode it without OpenSSL? How to prove that this code is ASCII (Base64) ?
Could you help?

Comment: openssl is the de-facto tool for this  kind of manipulation. whilst I rarely question people's motivations to do something in a particular way, I can't imagine many scenarios where not using openssl to decode a certificate would be useful.

Comment: If you are on Windows, you don't need to use OpenSSL at all, because it is external dependency, instead you can use built-in `certutil.exe` tool which can parse and decode many cryptographic objects, including certificates in PEM/Base64/DER formats.

Comment: *"How can I decode it without OpenSSL?"* - decode it into what? What do you want to achieve at the end? *"How to prove that this code is ASCII (Base64) ?"* - ASCII and Base64 is not the same. Please read Wikipedia what Base64 and Wikipedia is and then it should be obvious from looking at the data if fits the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEM files are base64 encoded binary data, this is a defined standard (so there's nothing to prove here). The reason for this encoding is spelled out in the intro of [RFC 7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#page-2):

> A disadvantage of a binary data format is that it cannot be
> interchanged in textual transports, such as email or text documents.
> One advantage with text-based encodings is that they are easy to
> modify using common text editors; for example, a user may concatenate
> several certificates to form a certificate chain with copy-and-paste
> operations.

The header (and associated footer) is used to denote what the enclosed data is.

As for the binary encoding, this is the DER or BER encoding of ASN.1 data, again as mentioned in the RFC:

> Several security-related standards used on the Internet define ASN.1
> data formats that are normally encoded using the Basic Encoding Rules
> (BER) or Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER)

Because these encodings output binary data, you're unlikely so see much of interest when dumping it, save maybe a few strings.

To decode without openssl, you'll need another tool that can handle DER (or BER) decoding as well as ASN.1. There are libraries available for those in most languages and there are likely to be other command line tools out there. But since you'll need an external tool, might as well use `openssl`.

PS: friendlier description of PEM is available on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail).

Comment: "The PEM format solves this problem by encoding the binary data using base64." This is the line from Wiki. As far as I understand, there is nothing DER ASN.1 in PEM where  base64 is used.
DER is for .cer certificates not PEM.

Comment: Sure there is. PEM is just the base64 DER output + header/footer. If you base64 decode a PEM certificate, you can parse the output as you would a normal `.der` file: `openssl x509 -in test.der -inform der  -text`. In short, PEM certificates tend to be: `base64(DER(asn.1_data))`